# rails: create posts using STI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, sti

I am using single tablable inheritance(STI) to create different types of articles.
But now I have problem while creating articles.(I can do it only in console).

Here are my models

Article.rb

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :title      
  validates :title, :presence => true
end
```

And TutorialArticle.rb

```
class TutorialArticle < Article
  attr_accessible :author  
  validates :author, :presence => true          
end
```

Here is  my _form

```
<%= form_for(@article) do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :type %>    

    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </div>

  <%= render :partial => "edit" + f.object.type.downcase, :locals=>{:f=>f} %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

But now I have a problem in article_controller.rb in create method

```
def create
    # create the desired subtype based on the hidden field :type in the form        
    @article = Object.const_get(params[:article][:type]).new(params[:article])      

    if @article.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created post."
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
```

Now when I fill in the form and press Create Article button, I get the folloiwing error

```
undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass
```

I even tried to hard code to understand what is wrong
 and  if I try to change `@article = Object.const_get(params[:article][:type]).new(params[:article])`

to

```
 @article = TutorialArticle.new(params[:article])
```

my create method doesn't save the article. it just redirects to create new article page.

Could you please help me to solve the problem?

Comment: can you add full backtrace?

Comment: If you print the @article.errors info to the screen, it should help you see why it's not saving.  But yeah, unless I'm missing something obvious, I don't see any blatant code issues.  Perhaps also include the debugging output for the contents of your params (if not printing automatically, do puts(params)

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel : Processing by ArticlesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"V", "authenticity_token"=>"0pegjWkYhPj1JHWCPYRzLTqe4Tw3U
DEYpX3uTWoUWZE=", "tutorial_article"=>{"type"=>"TutorialArticle", "title"=>"Tuto
rial1", "content"=>"my content", "author"=>"MyAuthor"}, "commit"=>"Create Tutori
al article"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 0ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:58:in `create'

---Is that what you were asking?

Comment: @GoGoCarl : I did. If I use the hardcoaded version, then it shows that my title and author shouldn't be blank. But they are NOT blank.

Comment: @lucy - they are - look. You refer to `params[:article]` but really you are sending `tutorial_atricle`. Can you paste `new` action?

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel-
 In my controller I have def new
   `@article = Object.const_get(params[:type]).new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @article }
    end
  end`
'
and in new.html.erb----
<h1>New article</h1>
´
<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel--- and in def new I get the  :type from index.html.erb <p><%= link_to "New Tutorial", new_article_path(:type=>:TutorialArticle) %>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the printing of params helped.  Add this to your TutorialArticle model:

```
def self.model_name
  return Article.model_name
end
```

This will make your forms pass article instead of tutorial_article, and the rest should work as expected.  You'll need this override in all your other Article subclasses.